# Can a GCM client (device) send message to another GCM client directly without going to server

Tags: registration, google-cloud-messaging

According to the documentation at

http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html

http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/server.html

A 3rd-party application server that you must implement. This application server sends data to a GCM-enabled Android application via the chosen GCM connection server.

From above,  it implies that you CANNOT send message from a client to another client directly.

Someone please confirm.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to send GCM-Messages directly from your Device to the Google-Server without any 3rd-party-server.
Just run an AsyncTask like this example:

```
  HttpPost httppost;
            try
            {
                httppost = new HttpPost("https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send");
            }
            catch (IllegalArgumentException e)
            {
                return false;
            }
            httppost.setHeader("Authorization","key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
            httppost.setHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");
            postParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("registration_id", "xxxxxxxxxxxxx"));
            postParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data.mode", "exampleContentOfYourMessage"));
            HttpResponse response;
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpEntity entity;
            try {
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParams, "utf-8"));
            }
            catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
            {
                return false;
            }
            try {
                response = httpClient.execute(httppost);
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                return false;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                return false;
            }
            entity = response.getEntity();
            if (entity != null && response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                Log.e("Tag","No Connection");
                return false;
            }
```

But I have no Idea how I may send a GCM-Message to multiple registration-Ids :(

Greetings, Malte

Comment: I get an authentication error while using this code.